# How to fix this error Trying to access array offset on value of type null using laravel?

Tags: laravel

How to fix this error Trying to access array offset on value of type null  using laravel ? please help thanks.

https://flareapp.io/share/17Dv2l6m

**controller**
public function update(Request $request, Event $events)
{

```
        $events->name = $request->name;
        $events->slug = $request->slug;
        $events->mf_year_id = $request->year_id;
        $events->date    = $request->date;
        $events->sort    = $request->sort;
        $events->type = 4;
        $events->save();

        AudioDetail::where('audio_id', $events->id)->delete();

        foreach ($request->title as $key => $value) {

            $audiodetail = new AudioDetail;
            $extension = Str::random(40) . ".mp3";
            $audiodetail->audio_file = Storage::disk('audiofile')->putFileAs('', $request->audio_file[$key], $extension);
            $audiodetail->title = $value;
            $audiodetail->audio_id = $events->id;
            $audiodetail->save();
        }

        return redirect()->route('events');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `isset`. For example `isset($request->audio_file[$key])`

Comment: i am getting error Call to a member function getRealPath() on bool

Comment: because isset returning true or false but I guess in this case you can not put anything in storage because you don't have audio file